# Using isEqualToString in IF statement with OR

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm using the next code to check if string is not equal to value :

```
if (![myString  isEqualToString:@"text1"])
//DO SOMETHING
```

now i'm trying to compare 2 or more strings with this code:

```
if (![myString isEqualToString:@"text1"] || ![myString isEqualToString:@"text2"])
//DO SOMETHING
```

and it's not working...when i separate it to 2 IF statements its working, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if (![myString isEqualToString:@"text1"] || ![myString isEqualToString:@"text2"])
```

But there is something odd with this logic. If it's not `text1` or it's not `text2` is always guaranteed to be true since it can't be both at once. I would strongly encourage you to review your logic condition.

It sounds to me like you want to check if it's neither `text1` or `text2`, in which case the code should be:

```
if (! ([myString isEqualToString:@"text1"] || [myString isEqualToString:@"text2"]) )
```

Comment: thanks, the second code was exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Inafziger you care to explain this last comment??

Comment: Nope, I just missed that you had put both comparisons between parenthesis.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `||` for an OR.

e.g. `if (![myString isEqualToString:@"text1"] || ![myString isEqualToString:@"text2"])`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something when myString isn't either of those values (the only thing that makes sense here) you would use:

```
 if (![myString isEqualToString:@"text1"] && ![myString isEqualToString:@"text2"])
      // DO SOMETHING
```

This uses the `&&` operator, which means that both of them have to be true.  e.g. "myString is not text1 **and** myString is not text2".